# How to run a part of code as root?

Tags: python, linux

For example I'm trying to edit a file, let's say `/etc/foobar`. And only `root` can edit that file.

The code looks like this:

```
# other code...

with open('/etc/foobar', 'w') as f:
    # other code...
```

Sure, run this script as root is the easiest way. But however I don't want to do that.

So is there any way to run only a part of code as root like `sudo` command does? Or how can I call `sudo` here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: As I said in question, this solution only *run the full code as root*. What about only *run a part of the full code as root* ?

Comment: Can't you use the same principle to return to non-sudo afterwards?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Wow, understand now. I could run the script with non-sudo again. Thanks :)